# Google Play Store requirement on minimum SDK support

Tags: android, google-play

As per [this link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) google play store says that now to publish an app developers need to make the target SDK version to 30. But there is no minimum support version specified in the documentation.

What is the minimum support version requirement to publish the app on playstore?

Where is an official document that mentions minimum SDK version?

Comment: I don't believe there's a minimum SDK. Just bear in mind even Google is stopping support for [Google Play services updates for Jelly Bean](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/07/google-play-services-discontinuing-jelly-bean.html) (API < 19) as pool of active devices is so low it's not worth the effort. I'd just got for 21 or even 23 which still account for about 95-85% devices but alleviates a lot of API headaches.